# In Facebook graph API, how to get reusable attachment data by its attachment_id?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

After uploading attachment, the API returns its id:

```
 {
  "attachment_id":"1857777774821032"
}
```

It says that if the attachment's is_reusable attribute set true, we can send this attachment to other people by this attachment_id. But, users can't memorize every id so, for that I need to be able to select from my previous attachments. How can I get my reusable Saved Assets? May be, I should save the ids to my database. But, I still need at least the preview of the attachment. So, how can I get the reusable attachment data by its attachment_id?

Comment: There is no way to get a list of all your assets, you will need to store these IDs on your end.

Comment: _“But, I still need at least the preview of the attachment.”_ - there is no preview either. You seem to misunderstand what the actual purpose of this is - to prevent that you have to upload the same data to Messenger API more than once. The purpose is _not_ to build a library of your assets on Facebook’s side, that you can “browse” at will. If you need to show your app user a preview of the image, then you need to use _your_ version of it, that you have stored in your own system.